# How can I use a Dictionary/StringList inside Execute of a Thread - delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, dictionary

I have a thread class TValidateInvoiceThread:

```
type
  TValidateInvoiceThread = class(TThread)
    private
      FData: TValidationData;
      FInvoice: TInvoice; // Do NOT free
      FPreProcessing: Boolean;

      procedure ValidateInvoice;
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
    public
      constructor Create(const objData: TValidationData; const bPreProcessing: Boolean);

      destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TValidateInvoiceThread.Create(const objData: TValidationData;
      const bPreProcessing: Boolean);
    var
      objValidatorCache: TValidationCache;
    begin
      inherited Create(False);
      FData := objData;
      objValidatorCache := FData.Caches.Items['TInvAccountValidator'];
    end;

    destructor TValidateInvoiceThread.Destroy;
    begin
      FreeAndNil(FData);
      inherited;
    end;

    procedure TValidateInvoiceThread.Execute;
    begin
      inherited;
      ValidateInvoice;
    end;

    procedure TValidateInvoiceThread.ValidateInvoice;
    var
      objValidatorCache: TValidationCache;
    begin
      objValidatorCache := FData.Caches.Items['TInvAccountValidator'];
    end;
```

I create this thread in another class

```
    procedure TInvValidators.ValidateInvoiceUsingThread(
      const nThreadIndex: Integer;
      const objValidatorCaches: TObjectDictionary<String, TValidationCache>;
      const nInvoiceIndex: Integer; const bUseThread, bPreProcessing: Boolean);
begin
  objValidationData := TValidationData.Create(FConnection, FAllInvoices, FAllInvoices[nInvoiceIndex], bUseThread);

      objValidationData.Caches := objValidatorCaches;
      objThread := TValidateInvoiceThread.Create(objValidationData, bPreProcessing);
      FThreadArray[nThreadIndex] := objThread;
      FHandleArray[nThreadIndex]:= FThreadArray[nThreadIndex].Handle;

end;
```

Then I execute it

```
  rWait:= WaitForMultipleObjects(FThreadsRunning, @FHandleArray, True, 100);
```

Note I have removed some code out of here to try to keep it a bit simpler to follow

The problem is that my Dictionary is becoming corrupt

If I put a breakpoint in the constructor all is fine

However, in the first line of the Execute method, the dictionary is now corrupt.

The dictionary itself is a global variable to the class

Do I need to do anything special to allow me to use Dictionaries inside a thread?

I have also had the same problem with a String List

Edit - additional information as requested

TInvValidators contains my dictionary

```
  TInvValidators = class(TSTCListBase)
  private
    FThreadArray  : Array[1..nMaxThreads]  of TValidateInvoiceThread;
    FHandleArray  : Array[1..nMaxThreads]  of THandle;
    FThreadsRunning: Integer;  // total number of supposedly running threads

    FValidationList: TObjectDictionary<String, TObject>;
  end;

procedure TInvValidators.Validate(
  const Phase: TValidationPhase;
  const objInvoices: TInvoices;
  const ReValidate: TRevalidateInvoices;
  const IDs: TList<Integer>;
  const objConnection: TSTCConnection;
  const ValidatorCount: Integer);
var
  InvoiceIndex:   Integer;
  i     : Integer;
  rWait : Cardinal;
  Flags: DWORD;     // dummy variable used in a call to find out if a thread handle is valid
  nThreadIndex: Integer;

  procedure ValidateInvoiceRange(const nStartInvoiceID, nEndInvoiceID: Integer);
  var
    InvoiceIndex: Integer;
    I: Integer;
  begin
    nThreadIndex := 1;

    for InvoiceIndex := nStartInvoiceID - 1 to nEndInvoiceID - 1 do
    begin
      if InvoiceIndex >= objInvoices.Count then
        Break;

      objInvoice := objInvoices[InvoiceIndex];
      ValidateInvoiceUsingThread(nThreadIndex, FValidatorCaches, InvoiceIndex, bUseThread, False);
      Inc(nThreadIndex);

      if nThreadIndex > nMaxThreads then
        Break;
    end;

    FThreadsRunning := nMaxThreads;

    repeat
      rWait:= WaitForMultipleObjects(FThreadsRunning, @FHandleArray, True, 100);

      case rWait of

        // one of the threads satisfied the wait, remove its handle
        WAIT_OBJECT_0..WAIT_OBJECT_0 + nMaxThreads - 1: RemoveHandle(rWait + 1);

        // at least one handle has become invalid outside the wait call,
        // or more than one thread finished during the previous wait,
        // find and remove them
        WAIT_FAILED:
          begin
            if GetLastError = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE then
            begin
              for i := FThreadsRunning downto 1 do
                if not GetHandleInformation(FHandleArray[i], Flags) then // is handle valid?
                  RemoveHandle(i);
            end
            else
              // the wait failed because of something other than an invalid handle
              RaiseLastOSError;
          end;

        // all remaining threads continue running, process messages and loop.
        // don't process messages if the wait returned WAIT_FAILED since we didn't wait at all
        // likewise WAIT_OBJECT_... may return soon
        WAIT_TIMEOUT: Application.ProcessMessages;
      end;

    until FThreadsRunning = 0;  // no more valid thread handles, we're done
  end;

begin
  try
    FValidatorCaches := TObjectDictionary<String, TValidationCache>.Create([doOwnsValues]);

    for nValidatorIndex := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    objValidator := Items[nValidatorIndex];
    objCache := TValidationCache.Create(objInvoices);
    FValidatorCaches.Add(objValidator.ClassName, objCache);
    objValidator.PrepareCache(objCache, FConnection, objInvoices[0].UtilityType);
   end;

    nStart := 1;
    nEnd := nMaxThreads;
    while nStart <= objInvoices.Count do
    begin
      ValidateInvoiceRange(nStart, nEnd);

      Inc(nStart, nMaxThreads);
      Inc(nEnd, nMaxThreads);
    end;

  finally
    FreeAndNil(FMeterDetailCache);
  end;
end;
```

If I remove the repeat until and leave just WaitForMultipleObjects I still get lots of errors

You can see here that I am processing the invoices in chunks of no more than nMaxThreads (10)

When I reinstated the repeat until loop it worked on my VM but then access violated on my host machine (which has more memory available)

Paul

Comment: You are likely not managing the object lifetimes and/or concurrency access correctly. It sounds you are sharing a single Dictionary across multiple threads. How is the Dictionary being used outside of the threads? You are not serializing access to the dictionary's content inside the threads.  Where and how does the dictionary get updated?

Comment: I initialize the dictionary before my threads are created and I dont make any other change to the dictionary to my knowledge.  I just use the dictionary to access data.  How do I go about serializing access?  I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Paul: depending on what you are doing with the dictionary, you may have to wrap access to it using a critical section or mutex.

Comment: ok I will have to try that on Tuesday that new territory for me as is most of this!  I am concerned that I get access violations on my host machine which is a better spec.  I have added more information now

Comment: We can't see the relevant code. You've omitted the code that matters.

Answer (score 3):

Before I offer guidance on how to resolve your problem, I'm going to give you a very important tip.

> First ensure your code works *single-threaded*, before trying to get a multi-threaded implementation working. The point is that multi-threaded code adds a whole new layer of complexity. Until your code works correctly in a single thread, it has no chance of doing so in multiple threads. And the extra layer of complexity makes it extremely difficult to fix.

You might believe you've got a working single-threaded solution, but I'm seeing errors in your code that imply you still have a lot of resource management bugs. Here's one example with relevant lines only, and comments to explain the mistakes:

```
begin
  try //try/finally is used for resource protection, in order to protect a
      //resource correctly, it should be allocated **before** the try.
    FValidatorCaches := TObjectDictionary<String, TValidationCache>.Create([doOwnsValues]);

  finally
    //However, in the finally you're destroying something completely
    //different. In fact, there are no other references to FMeterDetailCache
    //anywhere else in the code you've shown. This strongly implies an
    //error in your resource protection.
    FreeAndNil(FMeterDetailCache);
  end;
end;
```

---

#### Reasons for not being able to use the dictionary

You say that: "in the first line of the Execute method, the dictionary is now corrupt".

For a start, I'm fairly certain that your dictionary isn't really "corrupt". The word "corrupt" implies that it's there, but its internal data is invalid resulting in inconsistent behaviour. It's far more likely that by the time the `Execute` method wants to use the dictionary, it has already been destroyed. So your thread is basically pointing to an area of memory that *used to* have a dictionary, but it's no longer there at all. (I.e. not "corrupt")

> **SIDE NOTE** It is possible for your dictionary to truly become corrupt because you have multiple threads sharing the same dictionary. If different threads cause any internal changes to the dictionary at the same time, it could very easily become corrupt. But, assuming your threads are all treating the dictionary as read-only, you would need a memory overwrite to corrupt it.

So let's focus on what might cause your dictionary to be destroyed before the thread gets to use it. **NOTE** I can't see anything in the code provided, but there are 2 likely possibilities:

- Your main thread destroys the dictionary before the child thread gets to use it.
- One of your child threads destroys the dictionary as soon as it is destroyed resulting in all other threads being unable to use it.

In the first case, this would happen as follows:

```
Main Thread: ......C......D........
Child Thread       ---------S......

. = code being executed
C = child thread created
- = child thread exists, but isn't doing anything yet
S = OS has started the child thread
D = main thread destroys dictionary
```

The point of the above is that it's easy to forget that the main thread can reach a point where it decides to destroy the dictionary even before the child thread starts running.

As for the second possibility, this depends on what is happening inside the destructor of `TValidationData`. Since you haven't shown that code, only you know the answer to that.

#### Debugging to pinpoint the problem

Assuming the dictionary is being destroyed too soon, a little debugging can quickly pinpoint where/why the dictionary is being destroyed. From your question, it seems you've already done some debugging, so I'm assuming you'll have no trouble following these steps:

- Put a breakpoint on the first line of the dictionary's destructor.
- Run your code.
- If you reach `Execute` before reaching the dictionary's destructor, then the thread should still be able to use the dictionary.
- If you reach the dictionary's destructor before reaching `Execute`, then you simply need to examine the sequence of calls leading to the object's destruction.

#### Debugging in case of a memory overwrite

Keeping an open mind about the possibility of a memory overwrite... This is a little trickier to debug. But provided you can consistently reproduce the problem it should be possible to debug.

- Put a breakpoint in the thread's destructor.
- Run the app
- When you reach the above breakpoint, find the address of the of the dictionary by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + F7</kbd> and evaluating `@FData.Caches`.
- Now add a **Data** Breakpoint (use the drop-down from the Breakpoints window) for the address and the size of the dictionary.
- Continue running, the app will pause when the the data changes.
- Again, examine the call-stack to determine the cause.

#### Wrapping up

You have a number of questions and statements that imply misunderstandings about sharing data (dictionary/string list) between threads. I'll try cover those here.

- There is nothing special required to use a Dictionary/StringList in a thread. It's basically the same as passing it to any other object. Just make sure the Dictionary/StringList isn't destroyed prematurely.
- That said, whenever you share data, you need to be aware of the possibility of "race conditions". I.e. one thread attempts to access the shared data at the same time another thread is busy modifying it. If no threads are modifying the data, then there's no need for concern. But as soon as any thread is able to modify the data, the access needs to be made "thread-safe". (There are a number of ways to do this, please search for existing questions on SO.)
- You mention: "*The dictionary itself is a global variable to the class*". Your terminology is not correct. A *global variable* is something declared at the unit level and is accessible anywhere. It's enough to simply say the dictionary is a member of or field of the class. When dealing with "globals", there are significantly different things to worry about; so best to avoid any confusion.
- You may want to rethink how you initialise your threads. There are a few reasons you some entries of `FHandleArray` won't be initialised. Are you ok with this?
- You mention AV on a machine that has more memory available. NOTE: Amount of memory is not relevant. And if you run in 32-bit mode you wouldn't have access to more than 4 GB in any case.

Finally, to make a special mention:

> Using multiple threads to perform dictionary lookups is extremely inefficient. A dictionary lookup is an O(1) operation. The overhead of threading will almost certainly slow you down unless you intend doing a significant amount of processing in addition to the dictionary lookup.

#### PS - (not so big) mistake

I noticed the following in your code, and it's a mistake.

```
procedure TValidateInvoiceThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  ValidateInvoice;
end;
```

The `TThread.Execute` method is **abstract**, meaning there's *no implementation*. Attempting to call an abstract method will trigger an `EAbstractError`. Luckily as LU RD points out, the compiler is able to protect you by not compiling the line in. Even so, it would be more accurate to not call **inherited** here.

**NOTE**: In general, overridden methods don't always need to call **inherited**. You should be explicitly aware of what **inherited** is doing for you and decide whether to call it on a *case-by-case* basis. Don't go into auto-pilot mode of calling **inherited** just because you're overriding a virtual method.

Comment: Calling `inherited` to a virtual abstract method does not trigger an error. The compiler is able to  remove that call. `inherited Execute` would trigger the exception. For clarity, all inherited abstract calls should be removed though.

Comment: @LURD Ah, thanks for the clarification, I'll update that section accordingly.