# Delphi TThread handle error

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am reading "Delphi High performance" and there is something that I am missing. Given this code as test:

```
type TTest = class(TThread)
  private
    amemo: TMemo;
  public
    constructor Create(ss: boolean; memo: TMemo);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
end;

constructor TTest.Create(ss: boolean; memo: TMemo);
begin
  inherited Create(ss);
  FreeOnTerminate := true;
  amemo := memo;
end;

procedure TTest.Execute;
var i: uint32;
begin
  inherited;
  i := 0;

  while not Terminated do
    begin
      Inc(i);
      Synchronize(procedure
                  begin amemo.Lines.Add(i.ToString) end);
      Sleep(1000);
    end;

end;
```

Very simply, this thread prints some numbers in a memo. I start the thread suspended and so I have to call this piece of code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  thread := TTest.Create(true, Memo1);
  thread.Start;
end;
```

I have always stopped the thread calling `thread.Terminate;` but reading the book I see that Primoz stops a thread like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  thread.Terminate;
  thread.WaitFor; //he adds this method call
  //FreeAndNil(thread)
  //there is the above line as well in the code copied from the book but I have removed it since I have set FreeOnTerminate := true (so I dont have to worry about freeing the obj).
end;
```

At this point, if I run the code using only `Terminate` I have no problems. If I run the code with Terminate + WaitFor I get this error:

[image]

I have read more coding in delphi too and I see that Nick Hodges just makes a call to `Terminate;`. Is calling `Terminate;` enough to safey stop a thread? Note that I've set `FreeOnTerminate := true` so I **don't** care about the death of the object. Terminated should stop the execution (what is inside execute) and so it should be like this:

- Call Terminated
- Execute stops
- Thread stops execution
- Thread is now free (FreeOnTerminate := true)

Please tell me what I'm missing.

---

**Note.** 
In the book the thread doesn't have `FreeOnTerminate := true`. So the thread needs to be freed manually; I guess that this is the reason why he calls

```
thread.Terminate;
thread.WaitFor;
FreeAndNil(thread)
```

I agree on Terminate (stop the thread= and FreeAndNil (free the object manually) but the WaitFor?

Comment: Once you start a thread with FreeOnTerminate true then you must not use a reference to the thread again because you can't guarantee that it is valid.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think I've got it. When I call thread.Terminate; the thread dies and then, since FreeOnTerminate is true, the object is freed. Since the the object is free calling WaitFor won't work of course. (which is what you're saying)

Comment: So I think that Terminate + WaitFor has to be used when FreeOnTerminate is false (and of course remember to free the assigned object)

Comment: On a side note, you're not supposed to call `inherited` from within `Execute`.

Comment: That is added by default when I press ctrl + shift + g

Comment: @jerry doesn't matter, compiler removes it

Comment: @ruff The thread might terminate before you call terminate. If you must keep a reference you need to nil it in On Terminate.

Comment: WaitFor() should not be used with FreeOnTerminate=True, because the thread handle is closed when the thread object is freed, which is what causes the "handle is invalid" exception. FreeOnTerminate=True should only be used for "start-and-forget" type of threads.

Comment: @David I'm curious when that happened. I just tested and it is in fact ignored. But I do recall in the past it would raise `Abstract error` as it's flagged as `virtual; abstract;`. I can't find any information about it changing.

Comment: @Jerry It has always been like that

Comment: @JerryDodge LURD provided the distinction here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480402/how-can-i-use-a-dictionary-stringlist-inside-execute-of-a-thread-delphi/29516640#comment47233755_29516640 ... IMHO Superfluous **inherited** should still be deleted otherwise brain has to do a double-take every time the code is read. It's unfortunate that the IDE inserts it in places it does not belong.

Comment: @Craig Indeed, it should be very trivial to exclude `inherited` in `override` and especially `abstract` methods. The fact that the compiler ignores this case tells me a work-around was implemented instead of an actual fix :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Please tell me what I'm missing.

The documentation for `FreeOnTerminate` explicitly says that you cannot use the Thread in **any** way after `Terminate`.

That includes your `WaitFor` call, which would work on a possibly already free'd object. This use-after-free can trigger the error above, among other even more "interesting" behaviours.

Comment: The documentation is too lenient. You can't really access a `FreeOnTerminate=True` thread for **any reason**. The thread might terminate itself (crash, etc) before you have even had a chance to call `Terminate` at all. You should use `FreeOnTerminate=True` only for "start-and-forget" threads that you don't care about accessing after starting them. But once you need to access them for **any reason**, `FreeOnTerminate=True` becomes dangerous to use