# Parallel threads in Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi

TTask has been added since Delphi XE7.      I have an old application written under Delphi XE5 which I want to add parallel thread to.        Is there an alternative to using parallel threads?
Thanks

Comment: There are alternatives. You could look at [the omni threading library](http://www.omnithreadlibrary.com), which appears to have similar solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I wait for all threads in an Indy thread pool to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473409/how-do-i-wait-for-all-threads-in-an-indy-thread-pool-to-finish) - it basically gives a reference to the omni threading library as an alternative to the native support in the answer

Comment: @ Petesh: thank you, this is want I need. I forgot this library.